# Entering unicode characters into NCURSES form fields after user input

Tags: c++, c, forms, ncurses

Effectively, I would like a user to be able to enter a small number of unicode characters through using the Ctrl key. Ctrl + a will be "U+00E1 á or \u00E1" for example.

```
/* Loop through to get user requests */
while((ch = getch()) != KEY_F(1))//F1 for now
{   
    switch(ch)
    {
        default:
    /* If this is a normal character, it gets */
    /* Printed                */    
        if (ch == ctrl('a'))
        {
          /*FIELD *mycurrentfield = current_field(my_form);
          int my_index = field_index(mycurrentfield);   
          set_field_buffer(mycurrentfield, my_index, "\u00E1");*/
          form_driver_w(my_form, OK, '\u00E1');
        }
        else {
    form_driver(my_form, ch);
        }
    break;
    
    }
}
```

When I compile I get a warning and while the program runs I get a square in place of the unicode character I want. If I use any ordinary character, like say "#" it works so the issue is purely the form_driver functions do not like the unicode.

The warning

```
src/window.cpp:84:38: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   84 |           form_driver_w(my_form, OK, '\u00E1');`
```

I have compiled with the correct -lncursesw and -lformsw flags which are supposed to be able to take "wide" characters.

Further the ordinary print, and mvprint functions with those flags are printing unicode characters. I have included <locale.h> and the setlocale(LC_ALL, "") line before initscr() function.

I can change the form_driver_w function to form_driver(my_form, '\u00E1') and I will get the same warning. I also have the define #define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1 as well.

I tried a workaround by using the set_field_buffer function but this will only place the unicode character at the position 0 when and only when the first field is highlighted. And I cannot find a function to edit an index position inside of a field only.

It might be that there simply isn't a function to put a unicode character inside of a forms field, but it seems strange to me that ncurses print functions all will print unicode if I want them to.

Answer (score 1):

In both C and C++, `'\u00E1'` is a multibyte character constant / literal, which has the type `int`, and an implementation defined value.

<sup>See: [*C character constant*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant) and [*C escape sequences*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape), or [*C++ character literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) and [*C++ escape sequences*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) for details on language differences and portability.</sup>

[`form_driver_w`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/form_driver.3x.html) has the signature

```
int form_driver_w(FORM *form, int c, wchar_t wch);
```

which shows it is expecting a `wchar_t`, a *wide character*, which can be created by prefixing the constant / literal with an `L`.

```
L'\u00E1'
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I don't know how I forgot to try the L.

Comment: @II_Paulus_II - mark this reply as answer, please